# Software or API that lets us payout a custom amount of money automatically

Tags: automation, online-payment

First of all, we realize that there is some high risk involved here with automatically transferring money.

The idea is that we have a list of tasks all varying in length of completion and value for completion. Workers will then claim these tasks, complete them, and they would receive the value assigned to the task that they completed.

What would actually happen in our minds is that; the worker would complete the task, mark the task completed, the task would move over to a stack of all tasks completed, and then a moderator would then check all these completed task (validate them) to ensure that they are actually completed, and they would then be able to click payout on the ones that are actually completed.

Does anyone, know of any software or any API, that would let us achieve something like this, not something that does this exact, but some payment service like Google Wallet, PayPal or other with an API were something could be made or something.

**Some extra info:** Okay, we are interested in being able to make payouts based on a spreadsheet that acts as our database, so when a status changes, it will make a payout. That is it. So it will be linked to some sort of account with money on it, and it can then automatically transfer money from that system, when a status change is made in the spreadsheet. Mac OS or Windows works either way, and the budget doesn't really matter, whatever exists is what we will have to deal with.

Comment: Lots of requirements here.  What are you actually looking for?  Title suggests it's just about the payouts.   Also, you'll be asked about your preferred OS and budget.

Comment: Okay, we are interested in being able to make payouts based on a spreadsheet that acts as our database, so when a status changes, it will make a payout. That is it. So it will be linked to some sort of account with money on it, and it can then automatically transfer money from that system, when a status change is made in the spreadsheet. MacOS or Windows works either way, and the budget doesn't really matter, whatever exists is what we will have to deal with.

Comment: Seems like the PayPal API will support what you want.